# C++ integer digits to line by line

Tags: c++

I am working with my project that will convert the integer value to each line.
Example:

```
23487
```

Output will be

```
2
3
4
8
7
```

I know the code if I will used string, but I think its better if I use integer.

My current code using string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
string str("23487");
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
    cout << str[i] << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me if I use int instead of string?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/

Comment: Hint: you print 2 followed by 3487.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question -- you want to convert the actual integer into each individual single digit?

Comment: looks like an assigment/homework, it is pretty clear what (s)he is asking. btw you can allways print your integer into a string ...

Answer (score 2):

For integer values larger than 0, you can use this:

```
void Print(int val)
{
    if (val > 0)
    {
        Print(val/10);
        cout << val%10 << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice recursion but will it not be too much for a rookie?

Comment: @Spektre: It has occurred to me, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{

int value = 23487;

while(value > 0)
{
    int d = value % 10;

    value /= 10;

    printf("d = %d\n", d);
}

return 0;
}
```

Note that the digits will be printed backwards.

Comment: I think OP wants them printed forward.

Comment: Avoid using C standard library in C++. You also don't have to qualify functions with `void`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I hear. I hear ye.

Comment: @barakmanos I think that can easily be accomplished. Store the individual digits in an array then print the array in reverse order...

Comment: @JCM: Of course it can easily be accomplished... but your code does not accomplish it.

Comment: @barakmanos I know. It simply extracts the invidual digit and then prints it to standard output... storing the digits in an array is left as an exercise to the reader [hahahahaha]

Comment: It simply extracts the individual digit and then prints it to standard output **backwards**, which is not what OP asks for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... This code will print as exactly you want... :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int a=23487,ara[10],i=0,j;
    while(a)
    {
        ara[i++]=a%10;
        a/=10;
    }
    for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
    cout<<ara[j]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```